# Creating custom user roles

Tags: custom-post-types, user-roles

I need to create a custom user role who will be able to create posts (of a specific post type) but not publish them (just like the current [contributor role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities#Contributor).

I'm being a bit confused on how to create a new [role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) or [capability](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap) to achieve this. How/where do I start?

Thanks

**UPDATE:**
I added these to the custom post function as suggested by Eric Holmes

```
'capabilities' => array(
    'edit_posts' => 'edit_helps',
    'edit_post' => 'edit_help',
    'read_post' => 'read_helps',
),
```

Added these to plugin activation hook, and the opposite in deactivation hook (I'm modifying the contributor role itself):

```
function modify_user_capabilities() {
  $role = get_role( 'contributor' );
  $role->remove_cap( 'delete_posts' );
  $role->remove_cap( 'edit_posts' );
  $role->add_cap('edit_helps');
  $role->add_cap('edit_help');
  $role->add_cap('read_helps');
  }

register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'modify_user_capabilities' );
```

Now only the contributor can edit this post type, not other users (Eg admin)

Is there a better way to batch assign them these capabilities? I edited my activation hook to:

```
function modify_user_capabilities() {
  $role = get_role( 'contributor' );
  $role->remove_cap( 'delete_posts' );
  $role->remove_cap( 'edit_posts' );

  foreach (array('administrator', 'editor', 'author', 'contributor') as $user_role) {
    $role = get_role($user_role);
    $role->add_cap('edit_helps');
    $role->add_cap('edit_help');
    $role->add_cap('read_helps');
  }  
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**
I totally forgot to assign someone to delete the posts. So I updated the function:

```
function modify_user_capabilities() {

  //remove the contributor from editing any post
  $role = get_role( 'contributor' );
  $role->remove_cap( 'delete_posts' );
  $role->remove_cap( 'edit_posts' );

  foreach (array('administrator', 'editor', 'author', 'contributor') as $user_role) {
    $role = get_role($user_role);
    $role->add_cap('edit_helps');
    $role->add_cap('edit_help');
    $role->add_cap('read_helps');
  }
  //let admins delete posts
  $role = get_role('administrator');
  $role->add_cap('delete_helps');
  $role->add_cap('delete_publised_helps');
  $role->add_cap('delete_others_helps');
  $role->add_cap('delete_help');
}
```

Now the admin can delete these posts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a [role](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_role) is very simple. Creating custom capabilities is a little bit more to wrap your head around. When you [register your custom post type](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type), you define your capabilities for it. Essentially it is an array of "what do you want to count as this?". My example below will clarify this statement.

```
$caps = array(
    'edit_post' => 'edit_cpt_name',
    'edit_posts' => 'edit_cpt_names',
    'manage_posts' => 'manage_cpt_names',
    'publish_posts' => 'publish_cpt_names',
    'edit_others_posts' => 'edit_others_cpt_names',
    'delete_posts' => 'delete_cpt_names'
);
```

So, you would obviously replace "cpt_name" with your custom post type's slug (or anything you want really). The items on the left are the default capability names (there are more, so refer the the register_post_type entry in the codex). Whatever the capabilities you declare in your custom post type registration, you need to also give the User Role those capabilities:

```
add_role('basic_contributor', 'Basic Contributor', array(
    'read' => true,
    'edit_posts' => false,
    'edit_cpt_name' => true, // True allows that capability
    'edit_cpt_names' => true,
    'publish_cpt_names' => true,
    'edit_others_cpt_names' => false, // Use false to explicitly deny
    'delete_cpt_names' => false
));
```

Comment: Thank you. I'll be trying it when I reach that part of the project.

Comment: @rrikesh I think that's just about as good as it gets, unless you write a function which accepts an array of "roles", and then also an array of "capabilities"

Comment: Something like `add_caps_to_roles( {'administrator', 'editor'}, {'delete_cpt', 'manage_cpt'});`

Comment: No problem, @rrikesh!